# is it possible to access the NAME property of a frame in Actionscript 2.0?

Tags: flash, actionscript, actionscript-2, cs4

I name frame 50 `_foo` (in the IDE).

I can trace `this._currentFrame` at any time (and get a number).

I can `gotoAndPlay("_foo");`.

But how can I find out if the current frame IS `_foo` as the movie plays?

Is this possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In ActionScript 2 there is no way to access the Name / Label of the current frame (this feature was added in ActionScript 3).

However, you could use the following code to determine the current frame number at during playback:

```
// This is the frame number we want to look out for.
var targetFrame : Number = 50;

// Crate an onEnterFrame function callback, this will be
// called each time the current MovieClip changes from one
// frame to the Next.
onEnterFrame = onEnterFrameHandler;

/**
 * This function is called each time the MovieClip enter a 
 * new frame during playback.
 */
function onEnterFrameHandler() : Void
{
    trace("_currentframe: " + _currentframe);
    if (_currentframe == targetFrame)
    {
        trace("Playhead is at Frame: " + _currentframe);

        // Stop playback and remove the onEnterFrame callback.
        stop();
        onEnterFrame = null;
    }
}
```

For further reading, be sure to check the Adobe livedocs entry for [MovieClip.onEnterFrame](http://www.adobe.com/livedocs/flash/9.0/main/wwhelp/wwhimpl/common/html/wwhelp.htm?context=LiveDocs_Parts&file=00005321.html)

Comment: yeah, unfortunately the frame number is useless to me in this context. However, I'm simply creating my own property called _frameName and assigning a value to it at the appropriate frame and then testing to see if that's the value when onEnterFrame. Works just as well.